# Avoid TextField validation when the field is not focused - React Hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am new to React Hook forms. I'm using material UI TextField in my form.

I was able to display the error messages when I type in the Textfield.

But Once I clear the value inside the Textfield and click somewhere else on the page, the error still exists. I do not want it. I only want the errors to be displayed when user is typing in the textfield(example:- email regex check till the valid email is typed) or user submit a form without values.

I do not want the errors to be shown when Textfield is not focused. Can this be achieved by react hook forms?

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

function FormTest(props) {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    reset,
    formState: { isSubmitSuccessful },
  } = useForm({  mode: "all" });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSubmitSuccessful) {
      reset();
    }
  }, [isSubmitSuccessful, reset]);


<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
                  <Controller
                    name="email"
                    control={control}
                    defaultValue=''
                    render={({
                      field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
                      fieldState: { error},
                    }) => (
                       <TextField
                         label="Email"
                         variant="standard"
                         type="email"
                         color="warning"
                         value={value}
                         onChange={onChange}
                         onBlur={onBlur}
                         error={!!error}
                         helperText ={!!error ? error?.message : ""}
                       />
                    )}
                    rules={{
                      required: "Required!",
                      pattern: {
                        value: emailPattern,
                        message: "Invalid Email Address",
                      },
                    }}

                   
                  />
                  <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
```

When I click on the TextField and start typing the relevant error is displayed. But once I clear the field and click on a different place in the page the required error still exists. I do not want to show the required error when the text field is not focused. Only if it is focused and submit button is clicked without any values.

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.